# I'm trying to uninstall com.google.android.gms on my phone but I get an failure message?

Tags: android, sdk, google-apps

I downloaded SDK on my computer, connected the computer to the phone, recognized the phone so I can see my list of devices when I type ADB devices.

Now i'm in shell and when I type in the command prompt:

```
pm uninstall -k --user 0 'com.google.android.gms'
```

I get a: `Failure [DELETE_FAILED_DEVICE_POLICY_Manager]`

Is there a way around that? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Remove it from Privacy -> Device admin apps or find something like that.
Another solution is need to root your phone.